# How does Tab Listener work?

Tags: android, tabs, fragment, adapter, pager

I have 5 tabs using FragmentStatePagerAdapter. 
I want to work 4 tabs and the other tab at center differently. 
When I am touching this special tab, it is to be starting another Activity. 
and When I am swiping tabs, this special tab has to be passed.
How?

Comment: Can i ask you, Why did you want to do this? click on tab >>  starting another Activity?

Comment: no reason. I want to do this.

Comment: Okay please post your FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: It's very bad practice.